# parent overlapping child to create tab style effect

Tags: css, border, overlap

I have an existing css based dropdown menu. I would like to create a tab style effect by overlapping the border of the absolutely positioned child element with a white bottom border on the parent element:

```
----------------------
| Parent  | Parent 2 |
|          -----------------|
| Child content             |
-----------------------------
```

Is this possible by setting the z-index accordingly? I can't get this working.

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huo1rfL4/2/

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/huo1rfL4/)

```
<ul>
    <li>Entry

    </li>
    <div class="sub">

        </div>
</ul>

ul{position:relative;}

ul li
{
    display: inline;
    border-top: 1px solid #434343;
        border-right: 1px solid #434343;
        border-left: 1px solid #434343;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ffffff;
        z-index:200;
        background:yellow;
    position: absolute;
}

.sub
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid #434343;
     border-top: 1px solid #434343;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    top:20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi @himanshu, thanks for your answer, unfortnately I can't use absolute positioning for the tabs, as they need to be dependent on what is in them. Any other idea? I have updated the question

Comment: I'm looking at your fiddle in Chrome37 and there is a line between Entry 1 and .sub. I want this line gone, only for the width of Entry1.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/huo1rfL4/5/

you have create a onclick event to add and remove class active

Comment: Thanks again. I thought I have all the elements of your fiddle in my site, but for some reason it doesn't work: http://staging.theparentingplace.com (see blue border box overlapping green bottom border. Need it the other way around.

Comment: you want to sub div to ovelap tab...m i right

then make maximenuCK2 z-index higher than maximenuCK

Comment: No I want to tab to overlay sub menu. Green overlaps blue

Comment: the blue line under Early Years is because of hover effect no the case of z-index check it if it is that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61387/discussion-between-jdog-and-himanshu).

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="maximenuCK parent first item1068 level0 " style="z-index : 12000;">
```

change its z-index to 1200

```
<li class="maximenuCK parent first item1068 level0 " style="z-index : 1200;">
```

Comment: sorry that z-index is generated by the off-the-shelf menu system. But even changing it seems to have no effect for me?

Comment: Can't see this. See screenshot from browserstack. Blue overlaps green, but I want green overlap blue http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/ebrhyc.png

Comment: can you give bigger screenshot it too small to see